# In Rails, how to do a complex nested join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to generate this SQL statement via Rails:

```
SELECT * FROM reward_cards
INNER JOIN reward_card_payments 
  ON reward_card_payments.reward_card_id = reward_cards.id
INNER JOIN payments 
  ON payments.id = reward_card_payments.payment_id AND payments.amount < 0;
```

Is there a 'rails' way similar to this:

```
RewardsCard.joins(reward_card_payments => {:payments => payments.amount < 0})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could find is

```
RewardsCard.joins(:reward_card_payments).joins(
  'INNER JOIN payments 
    ON payments.id = reward_card_payments.payment_id AND payments.amount < 0'
)
```